# Close CMD window when command executes - Java

Tags: java, windows, cmd, sikuli

I'm using Sikuli to execute my automated tests, and I'm writing a small java app for running my tests. I've searched for other answers but most of them relate to running batch scripts from java, I need to run the entire command from java.I have the following command to run Sikuli from cmd:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait C:\\Sikuli\\runIde.cmd -r C:\\Sikuli\\xmlRunner\\runners\\Runner.sikuli --args 5");
System.out.println("Waiting for command to be executed");
p.waitFor();
System.out.println("Command finished");
```

This starts a new cmd window and starts executing my script but when the script finishes, it does not close the cmd window. Is there a way to automatically close the cmd window when my script finishes running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [close a particular command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618528/close-a-particular-command-prompt)

Comment: Did you try to chain `exit` after your command? Something like this: `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait C:\\Sikuli\\runIde.cmd -r C:\\Sikuli\\xmlRunner\\runners\\Runner.sikuli --args 5 & exit");`

Comment: Are you sure you want to see that console window?

Comment: If you don't want it to wait, why are you specifying `/wait`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `cmd /c start /wait cmd /c C:\\Sikuli\\runIde.cmd -r C:\\Sikuli\\xmlRunner\\runners\\Runner.sikuli --args 5`

See dock:

```
WAIT        Start application and wait for it to terminate.
command/program
            If it is an internal cmd command or a batch file then
            the command processor is run with the /K switch to cmd.exe.
            This means that the window will remain after the command
            has been run.

            If it is not an internal cmd command or batch file then
            it is a program and will run as either a windowed application
            or a console application.
```

When you directly call `runIde.cmd` the `/K` switch is applied, but when you proxy this call with `cmd.exe` this rule is not applicable.

Comment: If I remove /wait from the command it will go to the line "Command finished" even though the script has not finished its run.

Comment: Try `"cmd /c start /wait cmd /c C:\\Sikuli\\runIde.cmd -r C:\\Sikuli\\xmlRunner\\runners\\Runner.sikuli --args 5"`

Comment: @stewazy I adjusted my answer.